# POST ESP32 image buffer using HTTPClient to Node.JS API

Tags: esp32, node.js

I'm trying to post the buffer generated by the ESP32 camera to my personal API service I have built with Node.JS. The post gets sent successfully. I have yet to test it on large image (higher resolution).

I'm using a `FRAMESIZE_HQVGA,    // 240x176` for my images

```
void postImage(uint8_t* buf, size_t len)
{
  // prepare JSON document
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(len);
  doc["buffer"] = buf;

  HTTPClient http;   

  // Serialize JSON document
  String json;
  serializeJson(doc, json);

  http.begin("http://192.168.0.147:3001/api/pictures");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");     

  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(json); 

  if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
    // response
    String response = http.getString();
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    Serial.println(response); 
  } else {
    Serial.print("Error sending POST: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }

  // disconnect
  http.end();
}
```

In my Node.JSside, I receive the buffer but I'm unable to de serialize it to an image. This i smy body:

```
{ buffer: '����' }
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here. Should the image buffer be sent in base64, and if so, how? **I want to be able to transform the image buffer into a proper image on the API side.**

Here's my how I try to transform the image buffer to a proper image (in my API controller):

```
    const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body.buffer);
    const filename = `./resources/pictures/image_${Date.now()}.jpg`;

    fs.writeFile(filename, imageBuffer,function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(`Writing ${filename}`);
        }
    });
```

Comment: is there a specific reason to use JSON?

Comment: @Juraj No specific reason. Am I better off without it?

Comment: for JSON you would have to encode it as text (base64 is common). but you can upload it as any other classic file upload in the history of the www

Comment: JSON is a poor choice for large binary blobs. You would be better off just sending the raw buffer, with appropriate Content-Type (`application/octet-stream` if no other type is suitable) and Content-Length (the `len` parameter of `postImage()`).

Comment: @EdgarBonet Tried what you said. The body is empty when I receive the request in the API :/

Comment: @Johnnyboy: In that case you should debug the problem. Is the body sent? Did you look at it with a packet sniffer? Is the Node.js server discarding that body?

Comment: I'm currently looking at it with a packet sniffer, thank you for the idea! The request does get sent (I console log the request when i receive it, but the body is empty). So it's safe to say the api does see the request

Comment: @EdgarBonet Just to confirm. In wireshark, I do see the buffer in the body. For some reason the express API only accepts JSON

Comment: @EdgarBonet It works now. Thank you very much for the help! Really appreciate it!

Comment: would be better to send it to nodejs as a form file upload to avoid all the extra encoding.

Comment: @dandavis, but we are already talking about a binary upload